# Serial port timeout

Tags: serial-port, timeout, freeze

I am working with Biomic V3 with serial port communications and everything goes well till i send the EOT (end of transmission) character. I am using a background worker to do the write job. The serial port time out doesn't happens and the application hangs.

Communication flow:

Send: enqueue character

Receive: acknowledge character

Send: header

Receive: acknowledge character

Send: patient

Receive: acknowledge character

Send: instrument order

Receive: acknowledge character

Send: footer

Receive: acknowledge character

Send: end of transmission character (application hangs)

Can anyone help me with this problem because i ran out of ideas!
I thank you in advance!

```
    #region Static Variables

    private static AutoResetEvent _SendWaitHandle = new AutoResetEvent(false);

    #endregion

    #region Member Variables

    private object _Lock = new object();

    private BackgroundWorker _BackgroundWorker;

    #endregion

    #region Public Methods

    public void Write()
    {
        Monitor.Enter(_Lock);
        try
        {
            // Reset Handle
            _SendWaitHandle.Reset();

            // Send Data Logic

            // Wait for ACK
            if (_SendWaitHandle.WaitOne(1000))
            {
                // Send EOT
            }
            else
            {
                // Timeout Occurred
                // Your Logic To Handle Timeout
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            Monitor.Exit(_Lock);
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Private Methods

    private void SerialPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        // When ACK is received call SET
        _SendWaitHandle.Set();

    }


    private void backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        write();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Done it myself. Add a timer to the Serial port handler to avoid the time out